# SqlAlchemy: Caching hybrid_method results in the related object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two ORM classes like this:

```
class Road(Base):

  __tablename__ = "road"

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

  @hybrid_method
  def total_traffic(self, days):
      today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
      future_date = today_date+datetime.timedelta(days)
      return sum([traffic.volume 
                  for traffic in self.traffic
                  if traffic.date >= today_date and traffic.date < future_date])

  @total_traffic.expression
  def total_traffic(cls, days):
      today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
      future_date = today_date+datetime.timedelta(days)
      return select([func.sum(RoadTraffic.volume)]).\
          where(RoadTraffic.road_id == cls.id).\
          where(RoadTraffic.date >= today_date).\
          where(RoadTraffic.date < future_date).\
          label("total_traffic")


class RoadTraffic(Base):

  __tablename__ = "road_traffic"

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  volume = Column(Integer)
  date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
  road_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('road.id'), nullable=False)
  road = relationship("Road", backref=backref('traffic'))
```

This is functionally fantastic but on the full data set getting all the traffic data and summing it up locally is a bit slow (4 seconds in production) even with a joinedload. I can select total_traffic alongside the Roads like so:

```
  roads_with_traffic = db.query(Orn, Orn.total_traffic(7)).all()
```

but then I have to alter my views to receive this rather than the pure Road list.

Is there a convention on caching the selected total_traffic on the related object?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have gone about this at the moment is:

```
class Road(Base):

  __tablename__ = "road"

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

  def __init__(self):
    self.traffic_cache = {}

  @orm.reconstructor
  def init_on_load(self):
    self.traffic_cache = {}

  @hybrid_method
  def total_traffic(self, days):
      if days in self.traffic_cache:
        return self.traffic_cache[days]
      today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
      future_date = today_date+datetime.timedelta(days)
      return sum([traffic.volume 
                  for traffic in self.traffic
                  if traffic.date >= today_date and traffic.date < future_date])

  @total_traffic.expression
  def total_traffic(cls, days):
      today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
      future_date = today_date+datetime.timedelta(days)
      return select([func.sum(RoadTraffic.volume)]).\
          where(RoadTraffic.road_id == cls.id).\
          where(RoadTraffic.date >= today_date).\
          where(RoadTraffic.date < future_date).\
          label("total_traffic")
```

And updating the Road objects like so:

```
roads_with_traffic = db.query(Road, Road.total_traffic(7)).all()
for road, traffic in roads_with_traffic:
  road.traffic_cache[7] = traffic
```

Which is fine but it would be nice to move this inside the class some how.